# Exception occuring before the code starts

Tags: java

I have some code which is generating exceptions, apparently before the code itself starts.  I have no idea how to deal with this.
Here's the output:

```
Exception in_ sendUnsentNaggregation java.lang.NullPointerException
unsent: 0

unsent:
unsent:1
```

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
private void sendUnsentNaggregation()
{
    System.err.println("unsent: 0\n");
    try {
        log("unsent:");
        DateTime today=new DateTime();
        String nagID=String.format("Naggregation for %4d/%02d/%02d",today.getYear(),today.getMonthOfYear(),today.getDayOfMonth());
        log("unsent:1");
        Database.UniqueString uniqueNagID=db.new UniqueString(nagID,MAX_URL_SIZE);
        boolean alreadyThere=db.scannedURLs.indexOf(uniqueNagID)>=0;
        log("nagID "+nagID+" unique "+uniqueNagID+" today "+today);
        // wait until the naps site has stabilised
        boolean okayToSend=(today.getHourOfDay()>=5) && (today.getMinuteOfHour()>=55);  // send at 5:55
        if(nagNeedsSending.isSelected() || (!alreadyThere && okayToSend)){  
            String status=String.format("\nSending %s %s at %02d:%02d\n",(sendTestOnly.isSelected() ? "test " : "actual "),nagID,today.getHourOfDay(),today.getMinuteOfHour());
            browserPanel.append(status);
            scanner.updateNapsters(napsterROIThreshold.getText(),napsterSampleSize.getText(),napsterType.getSelectedIndex());
            if(sentNaggregation(sendTestOnly.isSelected())){
                if(!alreadyThere) db.scannedURLs.add(uniqueNagID);
            } else {
                browserPanel.append("Naggregation not sent\n"); 
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalSearch ex) {
        log("Illegal search in sendUnsentNaggregation");
    } catch (FileException ex) {
        log("FileException in sendUnsentNaggregation");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log("Exception in_ sendUnsentNaggregation "+e);            
    }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Print the stack trace. `e.printStackTrace`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and the complete stacktrace  (add `e.printStacktrace()` in your catch or use log)

Comment: I bet some money on `db` is null

Comment: Can you share more exception details?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, they led me to the solution, which was that the error was occurring in the evaluation of the parameters to the function.    I don't know why the JVM made the exception happen within the function, which was the part which was confusing me.